# Ordering of thread member relative to atomic bool member

Tags: c++, thread-safety

In this code simplified for SO `m_thread` is the first member of `Foo` and `m_ready` is the second member. Does this mean that `m_thread` can see an uninitialized value for `m_ready` or will the thread start after the other members are set (after `m_ready` is set to `false`)?

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

struct Foo final {
    std::thread       m_thread;
    std::atomic<bool> m_ready;

    Foo() :
        m_thread([this]() {
            while (!m_ready)
                usleep(1000);
            // Do work on other things only safe to touch after ready is true
        }),
        m_ready(false)
    {}

    ~Foo() { m_thread.join(); }

    void setReady() { m_ready = true; }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    // Initialize other things
    foo.setReady();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class data members are [initialized in the order they appear in the class definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Initialization_order). `m_ready` is declared after `m_thread` so it is constructed after `m_thread`.

Your `m_thread` [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) starts a thread of execution, the given function will start immediately.

There is a race between the thread reading `m_ready` and the constructor constructing `m_ready`. Put `m_ready` before `m_thread` in the class definition.